# Ruby: Call a method on returned object to detect if wrapper was used

Tags: ruby

I would like to return an object that outputs html or text and be able to call another method on it to ask it the wrapper was used. My code is much more complicated, but this should provide an idea of what I need to do.

```
    def callback(result)
      return wrapper(result) if result.length > 4
      result
    end

    def wrapper(text)
      h.tag.span class: "super-text" do
        text
      end
    end

Object.callback("test").wrapper? => false
Object.callback("test") => "test"
Object.callback("This is HTML").wrapper? => true
Object.callback("This is HTML") => "<span class='super-text'> This is HTML </span>"
```

Comment: I don't think you should be asking this question unless you need it for debugging. If you need to know if a method was called (e.g, `wrapper`) in production code I think you should restructure the code. In any event you don't want an instance method of `Object` because of its universal applicability. If `wrapper(result) == result` is never `true` and `callback` does not mutate `result`, then if `x = callback(result)`, just test `x == result`. Else, you couild use a hack such as `return [wrapper(result), true] if result.length > 4; [result, false]`, then `x, wrapper_called = callback(result)`.

Comment: What’s the draw back if defining the singleton method as shown?

Comment: Presumably `callback` returns a string, in which case `wrapper?` would be an instance method of the class `String`. How could that work? Also, don't you want the return value of `callback` as well as knowing if `wrapper` was called? Your examples don't provide the former. Signed, another lefty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Object inheritance

What you could do is to extend the [`Object`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Object.html) which is the he default root of all Ruby objects with your method. Something like

```
class Object
  def wrapper?
    false
  end
end
```

And then you return a different object when wrapping is happening. Something like:

```
class WrappedObject
  def initialize(helper, value)
    @helper = helper
    @value = value
  end

  # if this is necessary to do the wrapping
  def to_s
    @helper.tag.span class: "super-text" do
      @value
    end
  end

  def wrapper?
    true
  end
end
```

And in your function:

```
def wrapper(text)
  WrappedObject.new(h, text)
end
```

Of course it would be nicer to use [Ruby refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)

### Singleton Method

If you are using Strings then you could also define a singleton method on the returned value. Create the default method on the `Object` as previously described:

```
class Object
  def wrapper?
    false
  end
end
```

Then change your wrapper method:

```
def wrapper(text)
  return_value = h.tag.span class: "super-text" do
    text
  end

  return_value.define_singleton_method(:wrapper?) { true }

  return_value
end
```

You could also use [`Object#tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap) here, to make it more clever.

Comment: But then do you need to call to_s on the returned object?, if so it won't work for my needs

Comment: That was just a guess, it could be also `#to_html` I don't know what your framework is using. You could monkey patch the `span` what the helper returns if you want to apply this to the raw value.

Comment: is   return_value.define_singleton_method(:wrapper?) { true } thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

The object is stateless (unless there is a lot of class definition code you’ve not shared in the question) so it can’t tell you if the wrapper WAS used or not.

You could write a function to tell you if the wrapper IS BEING used, given a certain input.

`Object.wrapper(“test”) => false`

But it looks like you want to create an object with some “memory” of the input.

So, instantiate the object and give it some idea of state. Then you can work with your object like the below:

```
foo = LeftyObject.new(“test”)
foo.result => “test”
foo.wrapper? => false

bar = LeftyObject.new(“This is HTML”)
bar.wrapper? => true
bar.result => "<span class='super-text'> This is HTML </span>"
```